# Extracting data from associations in Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework

Tags: sql, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a simple entity structure defined in my project:

Country > Region > Province > Town

defined like this :

```
class Town
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=30,unique=FALSE) */
    private $townname;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $active;

    // so that we know when a user has added a town
    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $verified;


    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Province")
     * @JoinColumn(name="provinces_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $provinces_id;
```

etc.

OK. You get the idea.

Now, if a user has a town (many to one) then I would like to know the province, region and country for that user. I could make a repository method for the town entity that provides this data using SQL or DQL. Something like:

```
SELECT `users`.`towns_id`,`towns`.`provinces_id`,`regions`.`countries_id`,`provinces`.`regions_id` FROM users , `regions`
LEFT JOIN `towns` ON `users`.`towns_id` = `towns`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `provinces` ON `towns`.`provinces_id` = `provinces`.`id`
```

But this seems wrong, especially since doctrine already 'knows' about the relationships between the towns,provinces, regions and countries entities.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it like this:

I made the associations bidirectional (although this is probably not necessary):

```
// in towns entity
    /**
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Province", inversedBy="towns")
         * @JoinColumn(name="provinces_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=FALSE)
         */
        private $provinces_id;



// in provinces entity

/**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Town", mappedBy="towns")
     */
    private $towns;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->towns = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->active = true;
    }

    public function getTowns() {
        return $this->towns;
    }
```

You can simply reference a users country like this :

```
$user = new \Entities\User;
$user = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->findOneByFirstname('test');

$country=$user->getTowns_id()->getProvinces_id()->getRegions_id()->getCountries_id()->getCountryname();
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you want to retrieve those entities from database. May be better to use DQL if you want to minimize SQL statements sent against the db.

So for your situation I would add some DQL:

```
$dql = 'SELECT u, t, p, r, c FROM User u JOIN u.towns_id t JOIN t.provinces_id p JOIN p.regions_id r JOIN r.countries_id c WHERE u.firstname = ?1';
$user = $this->em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter(1, 'test')->getResults();

$country = $user->getTowns_id()->getProvinces_id()->getRegions_id()->getCountries_id()->getCountryname();
```

DQL operates on Classes and their properties (**NOT** on table columns). So by writing DQL you are actually using what doctrine 'knows' about your entity associations.

The above result set is equivalent when only one line is used:

```
$country = $user->getTowns_id()->getProvinces_id()->getRegions_id()->getCountries_id()->getCountryname();
```

But you get same results with one SQL SELECT query (with JOINS under the hood) instead of 3 SELECTS. And that would run faster.